# How to find Big O of a dividing recursive function

Tags: big-o

I am learning Big O and am stuck on a problem.

Problem -

```
int sample_function (int x) {
 if (x<1){
   return x;}
  
 int y = x/2; 
 return sample_function (y) + sample_function (x-y);
}
```

What will the big O be if we call 2 recursive calls of (n/2)?
I know that Big O of a dividing recursive function (n/2) is O(log(n)) but not sure about this problem.

Comment: Note that this is not a question about C or C++. It’s about the time complexity of this algorithm, which does not depend on what language you implement it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the recurrence relation

```
T(n) = T(ceiling(n/2))+T(floor(n/2)) + O(1)
```

is

```
T(n) = O(n).
```

This can be proved by induction on n.
The inductive basis is straightforward. As for the induction step, let c be a positive constant such that T(ceiling(n/2)) and T(floor(n/2)) are upperbounded by c * ceiling(n/2) and c * floor(n/2), respectively. Thus, T(n) is upperbounded by c * (ceiling(n/2) + floor(n/2) = c * n.

Answer (score 3):

Dividing an integer `x` by `2` to reach `0` takes roughly `log2(x)` steps. Each step doubles the number of function calls. For example:

```
  8
  4               4
  2       2       2       2
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In total thats [`sum( 2^k ), k = 0 ...log2(x) = O(x)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+2%5Ek%2C+k%3D0+to+log2%28x%29).

For `0` and negatives you return on the first call, thats `O(1)`.

*PS*: One can argue that the function is actually `O(1)`. A compiler might replace it with:

```
int sample_function (int x) {
    if (x < 1) return x;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + O(1) = 4 * T(n / 4) + 2 * O(1) = 8 * T(n / 8) + 4 * O(1) = ... = n * O(1) + (n / 2) * O(1)`

So, it's O(n).